# Increasing the the file upload size

Tags: php.ini

I put these inside wp-admin/php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 75M
post_max_size = 75M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Still not working, please advice if i am doing the right way or not?

Comment: I have two sites inside one hosting account. One inside public_html and another one inside public_html/addon-domain/ is this what you mean? I am using that codes in the first site.

Answer (score 2):

Please contact your host and ask them what is the default size of file a user can upload. They might have lesser value in their system. If you talk to them on their chat, I think this issue will be solved.

Answer (score -2):

rename your php.ini to php5.ini Some web hosting use php5.ini

btw. put it in the public_html folder or your main folder